# paintComponent is not being called in JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, paint

I have following code:

```
package hra;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class HerniPole extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    public int velikostPole;
    HerniPole(int velikostPole)
    {
        this.velikostPole = velikostPole;

        Color background = new Color(187, 173, 163);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
                {
                    System.err.println("Error!");
                }
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("2048");
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(background);
        frame.setSize(450, 450);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("xD");
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) 
    {
        System.out.println(ke.getKeyCode());
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) 
    {

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) 
    {

    }
}
```

And paintComponent() is not being called, nor paint() or even repaint(). What am I doing wrong? I've tried everything I found on StackOverflow, but nothing is working. How to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: You created a JFrame and made it visible.  But you haven’t added any components to it.  Perhaps you should create an instance of HerniPole and add it to your JFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a few things:

You don't have a `main` method (or may be you have but didn't post it in your question) and never created an `HerniPole` instance.
Add a `main` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HerniPole(0);
}
```

You didn't add your `HerniPole` instance to your `JFrame`.
Do that in the constructor, somewhere before `frame.setVisible(true);`

```
 frame.add(this);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post my main, frame.add(this); helped me. Thanks!